# Calculating distances between two atoms using mdtraj

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, if-statement, error-handling

i'm trying to calculate distances between selected atoms and mdtraj.distances generates an array, but i want to print, e.g. just distances smaller than 0.15 nm and the respective frame, but shows some distances. Anyone can give me a help?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import mdtraj as md

top_file = input("Topology file path: ")
traj_file = input("Trajectory file path: ")
index1 = int(input("VMD index of atom 1: "))
index2 = int(input("VMD index of atom 2: "))

traj=md.load(traj_file,top=top_file)
output = np.zeros((traj.n_frames,7),dtype=float)
for frame in range(traj.n_frames):
    pairs_frame = pairs_traj.xyz[frame,:,:]*10.0

atom_distances = md.compute_distances(traj,atom_pairs=[[index1,index2]])
    for j in range(atom_distances):
       if j < 0.15:
         print(atom_distances,frame)
       else:
         pass
```

Error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: What line do you get the error from? There should be a traceback of the functions called.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpspadeto/Downloads/distances-0.2.py", line 18, in <module>
    for j in range(atom_distances,frame):
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: I don't see such a line in your code. Line 18 there is `else:`. Check the values of `atom_distances` and `frame` if they are `int`.

Answer (score 0):

[`mdtraj.compute_distances`](https://www.mdtraj.org/1.9.8.dev0/api/generated/mdtraj.compute_distances.html) returns `numpy.ndarray`. You can't use it in `range`. Iterate over the array itself:

```py
for j in atom_distances:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the error.. but now i have another error rsrs, when i change the loop, the result shows correctly atom_distances < 1.5, because if goes to j. But i want to print when j < 1.5 and the corresponding frame, now the program prints every distances and last frame for all. What can i do?

Comment: @jaospadeto, the program prints exactly what you ask. If you want to print `j`, do `print(j)` in the loop.

Comment: Ok, it prints j, i want to put the frame corresponding to j, frame that is corresponding to the range of traj_n.frames. Do you know what can i do?

Comment: @jaospadeto, I don't get what you're asking. An [`mdtraj.Trajectory`](https://www.mdtraj.org/1.9.8.dev0/api/generated/mdtraj.Trajectory.html) object `traj` supports fancy indexing, so you can extract one or more frames from a Trajectory as a separate trajectory: `traj[j]`.

Comment: I'm trying to generate each distance and the corresponding frame, e.g. 0.16, 200 (0.16 nm distance in frame 200), but when i put: for j in atom_distances:, it generates distances proportional to the lenght of the atom_distances, but every distance has the number 9999 of frame (the last one), like, 
[[0.16]], 9999
[[0.15]], 9999

I wrote print(j,frame)

Comment: @jaospadeto, the `frame` variable you used is a mere specter of the `frame` used in the loop over `range(traj.n_frames)`. No wonder it never changes. Why should it? If you need indexing the distances, do `for frame, j in enumerate(atom_distances): print(j, frame)`.